# Extjs 4 create dynamic grid

Tags: extjs4

I am creating grid panel in extjs4 with below requirement :

- Coulmn name and column data should take from json file.
- Number of column should increase/decrease as per data exist in json.

I dont want to use any extension /plugin to do this, please suggest any pointer in extjs4.

Thanks,

Pravin

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure
Refer this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a Dynamic Grid with ExtJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993045/creating-a-dynamic-grid-with-extjs)