# How to read extra properties from model store EXTJs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, store, scope

​Json reader in is defined for the store as follows:

```
Ext.define('App.store.MyList', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model : 'App.model.MyList',
    pageSize : 100,
    proxy : {
       type : 'ajax',
         actionMethods : {
                    create : 'POST',
                    read : 'POST',
                    update : 'POST',
                    destroy : 'POST'
        },
        root : 'results',
        url : 'aaa.htm',
        reader : {
                    type : 'json',
                    root : 'results',
                    totalProperty: 'totalCount',
                    extraProperty: 'abcd'
    },
    simpleSortMode : true
     }
});
```

How do I read extra property outside the root? I tried to put one inside the `reader`, it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
grid.getStore().getProxy().getReader().extraProperty
```