# Nested JSON access outside of root data extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a model and store seen below:

```
Ext.define('Cookbook.model.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'key', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'title' }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: global.baseUrl + '/api/cookbook/1/1/8/8/-1?take=30',
        totalProperty: 'TotalRecordCount',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'Data'
        }
    }
});


Ext.define('Cookbook.store.Lists', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'Cookbook.model.List',

    root: {
        expanded: true,
        id: -1,
        name: 'All Lists'
    }

});
```

The structure of the json it is processing is shown below:

```
{"Data":
[{"title":"0 0asample cookbook","key":629},
[{"title":"0 0asample cookbook1","key":6291}],
"Count":568}
```

Now my question is: Is it possible to access the count using the Lists store eventhough its root is on Data?

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264428/how-to-read-extra-properties-from-model-store-extjs/18265966#18265966)

Comment: Thanks @MMT, that's great! I tried it but cannot find a way to get the count data from the json, is there any way i could pass it to extraProperty field?

Comment: try adding count property to reader

Comment: I tried adding the count property to reader but had no luck in retrieving the data. But I manage to get it using the answer I posted. Feel free to comment if there's another way to retrieve the data. Thank you!

Comment: You root is on Data, but Count is not in Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried adding count property but didn't get the results I needed. I managed to retrive the data by using the code below:

```
var st = Ext.getStore('Lists');
st.getProxy().getReader().rawData.totalCount
```