# How to implement Dynamic Grid in Extjs?

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs-grid

I want to implement dynamic grid in Extjs. I have found this [How do you create table columns and fields from json? (Dynamic Grid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979269/how-do-you-create-table-columns-and-fields-from-json-dynamic-grid/15282162#15282162) and the accepted answer looks good. 
In my case I have no proxy store but a proxy model:

```
 fields: [ {name: 'id', type: 'int', persist: false},
              {name: 'gender', type: 'auto'},
              {name: 'name', type: 'auto'},
              {name: 'age', type: 'int'}],

     identifier: 'sequential', // to generate -1, -2 etc on the client

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        idParam: "id",

        url:'http://localhost:3000/posts',
        api: 
        {
            read  : 'http://localhost:3000/db',
            create: 'http://localhost:3000/posts',
            update  : 'http://localhost:3000/posts' ,
            destroy : 'http://localhost:3000/posts' 

        },

        headers: {'Content-Type': "application/json" },     

        reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty:'posts',

        totalProperty: 'total'

        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
```

My store looks like is:

```
model: 'ThemeApp.model.peopleModel',

    storeId: 'peopleStore',
        pageSize: 500,  
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,     
        pageSize: 5,    

        autoLoad: {start: 0, limit: 5},
        autoSync: true,

        sorters: [{
            property : 'age',
            direction:'ASC'
                    }],

        groupField: 'gender'

});
```

In my view I have defined columns:[] But I don't know where to call metachange function.

Can anyone tell me where to use metachange function and should I use metachange function of store or proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you don't want to configure proxy on the model, that is only useful when you want to use standalone Model instances without a store.

Move the proxy config to the Store, and make the server respond to read requests with additional metadata object, which you can then use in the `metachange` event handler to configure the grid.

Using Reader metadata **is** the right way to do "dynamic" Grids.